# How to call program with array values as arguments?

Tags: arrays, bash

I would like to call a program by filling in the argument values with varying amounts of array values as in:

```
myarray=("val1" "val2" val3" ... "valn") 

program -t "${myarray[0]}" -t "${myarray[1]}" -t "${myarray[2]}" ... -t "${myarray[n-1]}"
```

I am essentially missing some way to expand the string `"-t ${myarray[i]}"` n times, where `n` is `${#myarray[@]}`.

Thanks for showing me the light!

Background:
I extract base names of files from a tab-separated file using `awk` filtering and store them in an array. Now I would like to run a program using these specific filenames as individual arguments of the same option.

Comment: Please tag your question properly. You tagged it as *shell*, which usually means "Posix shell", but your program is not syntactically valid Posix. In particular with this question, it might be important to know, which shell you are going to use, because the "best" approach might depend on the shell which you will use to run the program.

Comment: agree with above comments, but if you know about proper definition of arrays (in bash/ksh/zsh), surely you know how to reference them? i.e. `$myarray[1]`, etc. This is why showing actual code in your Q is important. What have you tried? Good luck.

Comment: Ok thanks. Did some edits.

Comment: Good update (mostly;-) ). Are all of your `myarray[]` values simple `0-9A-Za-z` text string with no space/tab/etc characters? If yes then you can safely use a `for` loop and build up your option list `optList="${optList} -t ${myarray[$i]}"`, then use that with your cmd, `program $optList`. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks so much, that did it. If you post it as an answer, I can mark this question as resolved.